# Join multiple tables in HQL

Tags: hibernate, hql

Can anyone help me to convert this query in to HQL

```
SELECT      
  supplierOrderDetails.productID,
  supplierOrderDetails.orderQty,
  supplierOrderReceiveDetail.qtyArrived
FROM
 supplierOrder
INNER JOIN
  supplierOrderDetails
ON
  (supplierOrderDetails.supplierOrderID = supplierOrder.ID)
INNER JOIN 
    supplierOrderReceive
ON  
 (supplierOrderReceive.supplierOrderID = supplierOrder.ID)
INNER JOIN 
    supplierOrderReceiveDetail
ON  
 (supplierOrderReceiveDetail.supplierOrderReceiveID = supplierOrderReceive.ID)  
   AND 
 (supplierOrderReceiveDetail.ProductID =supplierOrderDetails.ProductID)     
WHERE supplierOrder.ID = 1
```

Here is the table relationship

[image]

Comment: What error / stacktrace did you get? Or what other problem? More info is needed to provide a good answer.

Comment: I don't know how to get started...I am new to HQL...I am trying to search the internet but could not find anything...so last hope was post my problem here

Comment: You couldn't find any tutorial or example on HQL?

Comment: there are loads of tutorial but no where I could find how to join a sql like this in HQL

Comment: @ZAJ did you able to find the solution?

Comment: Yes I got the answer and I added it below as an answer for those who have similar issue

Answer (score 5):

I have added the query for those who want to know how to JOIN multiple tables in HQL

```
SELECT supplierOrderDetails.productID as product, supplierOrderDetails.orderQty as orderedQty,sum(supplierOrderReceiveDetail.qtyArrived) as qtyArrived 

FROM SupplierOrder as so, SupplierOrderDetails as supplierOrderDetails,  SupplierOrderReceiveDetail as supplierOrderReceiveDetail, SupplierOrderReceive as supplierOrderReceive

INNER JOIN supplierOrderDetails.supplierOrderID

INNER JOIN supplierOrderReceive.supplierOrder

INNER JOIN supplierOrderReceiveDetail.supplierOrderReceive

GROUP BY supplierOrderDetails.productID, supplierOrderDetails.orderQty
```

Answer (score -1):

This link is good to start learning how to join entity by HQL.

[HQL Join Reference](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#entity-inheritance-joined-table)

Edit :
For hibernate to join entities, you must have defined associations/mapping between entities.
Hibernate uses the relationship name defined in your Hibernate mapping file.

Comment: I managed to write the HQL query and join 3 tables but I am not able to add the last table to this join supplierOrderDetails.can you help me please                                                  `from SupplierOrderReceiveDetail sord
    join sord.supplierOrderReceive sor
    join sor.supplierOrder so`

Comment: The link is broken.

Answer (score -1):

HQL makes use of your mapped `Entities` and returns `Entities`. So depending on your hibernate (JPA) mapping, the HQL you want could be as simple as :

> from SupplierOrder where id = 1

- SupplierOrder is the class name of your mapped Entity
- id is the property name (instance variable) in your SupplierOrder
  class
- and I presupposed that all the other Entities where mapped with
  SupplierOrder class the highest in the tree hierarchy.

Comment: can you try to give me a start by trying to write this HQl for me

Comment: That's not possible without complete knowledge of your entity mappings.

Comment: I have added the table relationship

Comment: That's probably not completely the same as your entity mapping. Hibernate mapping with annotations like: `@Entity @Id @Column`.

Comment: here is the link to the hbm files

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/fmozk0h431b4xbu/vke4rTbd21